# In SQL Server Management Studio, does this type of query run faster?

Tags: sql-server, database-schema

My coworker showed me this query to look for a certain column:

```
 select * 
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 where COLUMN_NAME 
 like '%id%'
```

Does this help it run faster, to use the `.COLUMNS` notation?

thanks a lot?

Comment: Run faster than what? Usually queries against the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are less efficient than the `sys.` equivalents, particularly when it comes to joining them as the `id` columns are not exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Martin. I much prefer this query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id), OBJECT_NAME(object_id), name
  FROM sys.columns
  WHERE name LIKE '%id%';
```

The reason I prefer `sys.` over `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.`? Mostly because - while the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are standard - they're already incomplete, and to add insult to injury they don't pick up new features in newer versions of SQL Server. [I blogged about it here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

But your question seems to be missing some context in any case. What other methods of "looking for a certain column" are you comparing this to?